# Can async generators run concurrently?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, generator, coroutine

I'm trying to understand async generators and its practical use-case better. So, I wrote this code

```
import asyncio

async def download(urls):
    for url in urls:
        print(f"Downloading page at {url} started")
        await asyncio.sleep(2) # simulating a page download
        print(f"Page downloaded from {url}")
        yield f"Page downloaded from url {url}"

async def main():
    results = []
    async for i in download(["foo.com", "bar.com", "baz.com"]):
        results.append(i)

    print("All results:", results)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code return this output:

```
Downloading page at foo.com started
Page downloaded from foo.com
Downloading page at bar.com started
Page downloaded from bar.com
Downloading page at baz.com started
Page downloaded from baz.com
All results: ['Page downloaded from url foo.com', 'Page downloaded from url bar.com', 'Page downloaded from url baz.com']
```

The pages are not downloaded concurrently here.

I understand that without the async generator I can simply use the following to create independent coroutines to download the pages concurrently:

```
async def download(url):
    print(f"Downloading page at {url} started")
    await asyncio.sleep(2) # simulating a page download
    print(f"Page downloaded from {url}")
    return f"Page downloaded from url {url}"

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[download(x) for x in ["foo.com", "bar.com", "baz.com"]])

asyncio.run(main())
```

However I do not get the point of using async generators. Can someone explain a practical use-case of async generators with some code(if possible) or point me to a blog etc.?

Thanks

Comment: TL;DR: they can run concurrently in the sense that you can have any number instances of the function you call `main()` running in the same event loop. But each individual async generator is sequential - it just knows how to suspend while producing the next item.

Comment: Cool, thanks - This was the key for my understanding "The underlying misunderstanding is expecting async for to automatically parallelize the iteration. It doesn't do that, it simply allows sequential iteration over an async source"